# Scheduling jenkins builds once in 5 days

Tags: jenkins

I am new to **Jenkins**. I want my job to run **`once in 5 days`** periodically. What are the parameters I need to pass in build periodically under build triggers option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `Build Periodically` parameter under `Build Triggers` to following value:

```
* * */5 * *
```